# Cannot create kendo chart valueAxis template label in another function

Tags: javascript, kendo-chart

```
valueAxes: [
{
    name: "A",
    labels: {
        visible: true,
        template: temp("#= value #"),
        color: "#888"
    },


function temp(value){
return (value/1000) // in here i cant do any operation :( 
}
```

How can I do this type of operation? And this operation value will not pass to my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like

`template: "#= temp(value) #"`